# R help - why can't I download the nortest package on my work computer?

Tags: r, package

I need to use R to do some stats at work. The problem is, when I try and download the [nortest package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=nortest), using the following function:

```
install.packages("nortest")
```

Or by selecting 'install packages' from the R menu (NB.: I am using a UK CRAN mirror), I get the following error message:

```
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : 
  Line starting '<head><title> ...' is malformed!
```

I spoke to the IT dept at work and they mentioned that because R is open source, there are blocks on downloading certain things - and we ran a check and the system was blocking my download of nortest, for security reasons. The IT guy did say he wouldn't mind lowering the block just once, if I could then save the (zip?) file so I didn't need to access the internet every time I loaded up the package.

The problem is, I have no idea how to get a copy of 'nortest' as a zip file. And then once I have it, I don't know how to save it so that it loads from a saved file rather than selecting 'install package' from the R menu.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Kate

Comment: You need a more permanent solution than "just this once".  There are always more interesting R packages to download.

Comment: As per my comment below, sometimes you can install the source (`.tar.gz`) version of the package. It's possible that your system would be less fussy about `.tar.gz` files (which are less common and probably less infected with malware, on average, than `.zip` files)

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Windows, try using [`setInternet2`](http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/04/15/friday-function-setinternet2/) so that your IT network thinks that it is Internet Explorer connecting to the internet. Often useful for evading corporate lockdown.

Comment: To add: It has to be done at the beginning of session otherwise `Warning in setInternet2(TRUE) : internet routines were already initialized` could happens. (strictly: before any try of internet access)

Answer (score 2):

Ask your site IT to add an exception to their firewall/content blocking for this CRAN mirror, or download it elsewhere and transfer the file to where you need it:

http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/web/packages/nortest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should know, that if you have installed the package you don't need to download it again (unless you delete it purposefully from your R folder). just load it with `require(nortest)` and it will fetch it from your hard drive. So you could go with the just once solution provided by your IT guys.

However, there will always be other interesting packages, e.g. (for me): stringr, reshape, ez, ...
So you will need a permanent solution.

If it does not work with `setInternet2` as Richie Cotton suggested there is another way of getting packages.

You can download the zip files directly from the web page on cran. For nortest the direct link to the zip is the following: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/nortest_1.0.zip
Then, you need to change the working directory of r (see `?getwd` ans `?setwd`) to the directory that contains the zip file and install it directly from your harddrive within R with:

```
install.packages("nortest_1.0.zip", repos = NULL)
```

This works for any package with the correct file name.

Comment: This method is painful when comes to dependencies. (+1 for solving problem by install from .zip file)

Comment: Please also mention that to be able to do this under Windows, you'll need RTools ( http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/ ) to build from source.

Comment: @Joris: if (as in the case of `nortest`) the package has no compiled C/Fortran components, I think you can get away with downloading the `.tar.gz` file and installing from source, even without RTools ... And Henrik's answer above refers to the binary (`.zip`), not the source version, of the package ...